# how to check if form submitted in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to check if the form submit button is clicked so I tried:

```
if($request->input('submit')){
    //do something
    }
```

and tried:

```
$clicked=$request->input('submit');
if(isset($clicked)){
    //do something
    }
```

and also tried:

```
if($request->input('submit')!=null){
    //do something
    }
```

but when I do click the submit button in the form the execution of if-inside never happens so what is the right way to check if submit button clicked in laravel?

Comment: are you submitting form using GET or POST?

Comment: I am submitting the form using POST

Comment: are you submitting at the post route have defined any?

Comment: here is the route :
Route::any('/messaging/{group_id}', 'messagesController@mainMessaging')

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz I am posting to the route I menationed

Answer (score 4):

Check if the value of submit button is set. This might be the easiest also, I always use it.

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" name="find" value="Find">Find</button>
```

LARAVEL:

```
if (isset($request->find)) 
{
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are submitting the using POST method then you can check whether it is submitted via POST

```
if($request->method() == 'POST'){
//ur code here
}
```

Comment: your method worked but it works only if the form has just one button I have answered my own question if you do not mind and I have included your answer with your name

Answer (score 2):

this can be solved two ways:
first way if your form contains just one button and your form is using POST then like Adnan Mumtaz said we can use :

```
if($request->method() == 'POST'){
//ur code here
}
```

but if the form contains multiple buttons and we want check if button than have name btn1 clicked then we can use:

```
if($request->has('btn1')){
//rest of the  code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is what I am using :

```
if($request->has('submit')){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get()` methid of request

```
if($request->get('submit')){
//do something
}
```

Make sure in view you have given button name `submit`

Comment: I think it will always return true

Comment: when i use it like you said i get error:
Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression

Comment: checked out but not working and i have tried to replace get with post also but not working either

Answer (score 0):

For example if your submit button html is like below

`<input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="add">`

```
if($request->submit_btn == 'submit')
{
     //code
}
```

Here it compare that if the submit_btn value is submit it means if submit ckicked.
Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

As your are supposed to always use `@csrf` in your `<form>`, Then you can check

```php
if (request()->input('_token')) // null = false
```

Also, if you want to check that your `<form>` **was sent but failed**, you can also check

```php
if (!empty(old())) // old() also contain the `_token` field
```